# How should I design this program?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I am writing a program in Java. The picture is self-explanatory -

[image: Design]
The main method spawns three threads. The SAX processor processes the input XML file, generates JAXB objects and puts them in guava cache. Guava cache is handled by another thread. Whenever any object comes into the cache, this thread notifies the third thread which is the MDL generator (it relates the similar JAXB objects, interconnects them and generates another XML file, called MDL). I have coded the following for the main class -

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ExecutorService xMLService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        xMLService.execute(new XMLProcessor());

        ExecutorService cacheService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        cacheService.execute(new CacheProcessor());

        ExecutorService mdlService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        mdlService.execute(new MDLProcessor());

        xMLService.shutdown();
        cacheService.shutdown();
        mDLService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But now I have doubts regarding how to pass objects between the threads and how to notify the MDL generator whenever a new object comes to the cache. In Java old threading model we could use notify(), but I want to use the current ExecutorService. And there are asynchronous callbacks. So I am wondering how to design this framework. How to pass objects and notify the threads? We are keeping the cache objects in HashMap and the CacheService thread needs to pass the key to the MDLService. So which pattern should I use?

Comment: Hello. This is a good conception problem. I don't think there's one absolute solution. IMO, this is a good use case to introduce queue processing.  Your `XMLProcessor` publish the results in a queue then your `CacheProcessor` listen to the queue and process items and same for `CacheService` and `MDLService`.

Comment: In your program you do not need three thread to work,the thread used to process can removed,then the Guava Cache also don't need,you can use a BlockingQueue to instead.SAX processor process XML input and add to BlockingQueue,and MDL generator get data from BlockingQueue.if you need a code example i can support.

Comment: Hi @TongChen: I need the Guava cache since the MDL Generator needs to query it multiple times with the hashkey (which should be passed from the Cache thread itself) to generate the MDL. So if the objects are in Cache, it will be faster. As a matter of fact we can put the xMLService and the cacheService within the same thread if it simplifies the problem. So first thread generates a hashmap,  notifies the second thread and passes the hashkey. How this can be done? The run() method doesn't accept arguments. So how we can notify and pass a String at the same time?

Comment: You might want to have a look at Guava [EventBus](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Guava/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html). It is a little primitive in what it can do (and still beta), but usable for simple cases. All executors would move under `EventBus` control. Passing an object transforms into posting it to the bus by producer and asynchronous invocation of callback on the consumer side. All dispatching is done based on the class type of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example implementation for the above described case. Please note that the implementation could have been possible even without Guava cache, as mentioned by some of the others who have replied; nevertheless I presume there may have been a valid reason for Nirmalaya to ask for it. One such reason that I could think about is spilling over of the cache to storage devices or databases, to save upon the runtime memory.

**employee-records.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <name>Thomas</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <name>Lisa</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="3">
        <name>Ronald</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="4">
        <name>Erica</name>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.technoroy.examples.guava;

/**
 * A value holder POJO implementation for Employee records
 * @author Rahul R
 *
 */
class Employee {
    private Integer id = null;
    private String name = null;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**GuavaCacheProcessor.java**

```
package com.technoroy.examples.guava;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

/**
 * The primary executable class
 * 
 * @author Rahul R
 *
 */
public class GuavaCacheProcessor {
    private final static BlockingQueue<Integer> notificationQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        Runnable xmlProcessor = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                parseDataFile();
            }
        };

        Runnable mdlGenerator = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        Integer id = notificationQueue.take();
                        Employee record = ApplicationCacheUtil.getRecord(id);
                        generateContent(record);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.submit(xmlProcessor);
        executorService.submit(mdlGenerator);
    }

    public static void generateContent(Employee employee) {
        System.out.println(employee);
    }

    public static void parseDataFile() {
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream dataInputStream = GuavaCacheProcessor.class.getResourceAsStream("employee-records.xml");

        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(dataInputStream, new DefaultHandler() {
                private Employee employee = null;
                private StringBuilder elementValue = null;

                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
                        employee = new Employee();

                        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
                        if (id.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                            employee.setId(Integer.valueOf(id));
                        }
                    }

                    elementValue = new StringBuilder();
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    if (elementValue != null) {
                        elementValue.append(new String(ch, start, length));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                        if (employee != null && elementValue != null) {
                            employee.setName(elementValue.toString());
                        }
                    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
                        ApplicationCacheUtil.putRecord(employee.getId(), employee);
                        try {
                            notificationQueue.put(employee.getId());
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    elementValue = null;
                }
            });
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The Cache utilities class, that initializes and returns a handle to the
 * cache.
 * 
 * @author Rahul R
 *
 */
class ApplicationCacheUtil {
    private static Cache<Integer, Employee> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();

    public static Cache<Integer, Employee> getCache() {
        return cache;
    }

    public static void putRecord(Integer key, Employee value) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    public static Employee getRecord(Integer key) {
        return cache.getIfPresent(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I had missed the comment that described the reason why @Nirmalaya needs to use Guava cache, in one of his comments to TongChen.

Comment: Hi @Rahul R - thanks a lot for the most detailed answer I could have ever expected! Take a bow.

Answer (score 4):

> How to pass objects and notify the threads? We are keeping the cache objects in HashMap and the CacheService thread needs to pass the key to the MDLService. So which pattern should I use?

Seems to me that you have 1 thread too many.  The XML reading thread and the MDL writing make sense, but a thread to just put things into an in-memory cache seems to be too complicated.  If the MDL generator needs to use the Guava cache then it should "own" the cache and stick things into it.

That leaves you with 1 input SAX processor thread and one output MDL generator thread.  Good.  To connect the two I would use a `BlockingQueue` like the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.  You may or may not want to set a size limit on the queue depending on whether or not the reading is faster than the writing and how many records in your job.

So you main thread will create the `BlockingQueue` and then pass it to both the input and output threads.  The SAX input thread calls `put()` on the queue and the MDL output thread calls `take()` puts the object into the Guava cache and then does the MDL generation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Guava Cache, you can use Guava AsyncEventBus for disopatching messages between the tasks and do away with the three separate dedicated ExecutorServices.

Comment: This should be a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: @Stultuske You are expected to explain why. This was neither a request for more information or suggestion for improvement but an answer to the question "how to pass objects between the threads and how to notify the MDL generator whenever a new object comes to the cache". The fact that the answer is short doesn't mean it should be a comment.

Comment: it was actually a question you asked him.

Comment: So your request is for me to rephrase my answer in a form that does not contain a question? By all means go on and edit the format of my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: it aren't my needs. You just post something you are not sure of, you indicate yourself that basically, you're just guessing. which is why it's more a comment

Comment: The original question is so broad and on so high level that there are no definitive answers. But it doesn't matter. My question was not about the question itself. It was a suggestion for a solution, which qualifies as an answer. You are only complaining about semantics. "You could probably use Guava AsyncEventBus" is the same answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188882/discussion-between-torben-and-stultuske).

Comment: it's not really intended as a discussion :)
I just gave my opinion, and, after you asked for my reason, I gave that as well

Comment: I edited one word and magically everything is great. We cool?